# Two button events are not triggering at the same time in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have 2 buttons side by side:
`Current year PR signature` and `Prior year PR signature`

When I am clicking on Current year or prior year PR signature button for the first time, it gives me the grid data of current year or prior year.

When I am clicking on Current or prior year PR signature for the second time, the button event is not triggering.

can anyone give me any suggestion to resolve this issue.

The expectation is the button should be triggered after clicking for the second time.

```js
// Button click event for Current Year PR Signatures
$('#SignatureMaintenance_Currentyearreporting_Button').on('click', function () {
  //logic
});
```

```js
// Button click event for Prior Year PR Signatures
$('#SignatureMaintenance_Prioryearreporting_Button').on('click', function () {
  //logic
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara I click on current year pr button,it populates the data of current year. i click on prior year pr button, so here button event is not triggering.
same happens with the viceversa.

Comment: We need to see your html and logic to debug this. We don't know if the prior year button's id is invalid or if the logic is bad because we can't see it.

Comment: You can create a runnable snippet with the `<>` button. Without you sharing all the potentially responsible code it is a guessing game for us as well.

Comment: does your functionality rewrite the buttons? that would do it. I'm assuming you've added diagnostics to confirm the event itself is not triggering rather than the desired action simply not happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by making the below code changes to the button click event.

$(document).on('click', '#SignatureMaintenance_Currentyearreporting_Button', function () {
//logic
});

$(document).on('click', '#SignatureMaintenance_Prioryearreporting_Button', function () {
//logic
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).